# Getting a string from a in specific h2 header

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have html which have couple headers. Single one looks like this:

```
<h2 class="product-name">
                <a href="url">
                    text</a>
            </h2>
```

How I can get the 'text' only if there is class=product-name in the h2?
I tried some ways to do this and none of them worked.

Comment: `soup.find_all('h2',{'class':'product-name'})`

Comment: I tried it and it prints only a "None" dozen of times.
        `        for link in soup.find_all('h2',{'class':'product-name'}):
            title = link.string
            print title`

Comment: You want `link.text` and not `link.string`

Comment: Oh, that was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome!